# Looping through array in PHP returned Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Tags: php, arrays

I am sending an array over HTTP POST to backend API which  is PHP.

**js**

```
var form_data = [];
for (var k = 0; k < $scope.Tablelist.length; k++){
  if($scope.Tablelist[k].selected == true){
    var id = $scope.Tablelist[k].id;
    var docno = $scope.Tablelist[k].quote_no;
    form_data.push({id: id, docno:docno})
  }
}
if(form_data.length>0){
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: "api/purchase/purchase.php",
    data: {
      modul: 'PRICE',
      action: 'delete',
      form_data: form_data,
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
  })
```

**PHP**

```
$form_data = (array)$request->form_data;
foreach ($form_data as $key => $value) {
     echo "Key: $key; Value: $value";
}
```

it gave me an error `Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`.

I am trying to get the value of `id` and `docno` of each array.

How can i do that?

**var_dump($form_data)**

`"array(3) {↵  [0]=>↵  object(stdClass)#3 (2) {↵    ["id"]=>↵    string(1) "6"↵    ["docno"]=>↵    string(5) "test4"↵  }↵  [1]=>↵  object(stdClass)#4 (2) {↵    ["id"]=>↵    string(1) "7"↵    ["docno"]=>↵    string(5) "test3"↵  }↵  [2]=>↵  object(stdClass)#5 (2) {↵    ["id"]=>↵    string(1) "4"↵    ["docno"]=>↵    string(5) "test2"↵  }↵}↵"`

**var_dump($request->form_data)**

`"array(3) {↵  [0]=>↵  object(stdClass)#3 (2) {↵    ["id"]=>↵    string(1) "6"↵    ["docno"]=>↵    string(5) "test4"↵  }↵  [1]=>↵  object(stdClass)#4 (2) {↵    ["id"]=>↵    string(1) "7"↵    ["docno"]=>↵    string(5) "test3"↵  }↵  [2]=>↵  object(stdClass)#5 (2) {↵    ["id"]=>↵    string(1) "4"↵    ["docno"]=>↵    string(5) "test2"↵  }↵}↵"`

Comment: can you share the `var_dump` or `print_r` of `$form_data` or `$request->form_data`?

Comment: updated with var_dump

Comment: which one?? `$form_data` or `$request->form_data`

Comment: updated with both of $form_data and $request->form_data

Comment: Your `$value` is not a string. `$value->docno` and `$value->id` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember one things, The type casting of like this never convert the inner Object. So you need to access them using the `->` sign.

> And your `$value` is also an array you can't echo it.

From your `var_dump` of objects, you can notice that the inner array looks an object not array. So i suggest to use this as object.

> **Important:** You can encode as  `json` the `form_data` in your
>   JavaScript code and in PHP just decode with `true` properties so that
>   you can get an associative array.

As per your requirement, *I am trying to get the value of id and docno of each array.*

```
$form_data = (array) $request->form_data;
foreach ($form_data as $key => $value) {
    echo "Key:".$key;
    echo $value->docno." and ".$value->id;
}
```

Try to access the inner array as object or again type case it.

**Note:** Also you can use **`get_object_vars`** for type case an object to an array. [More details](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, i am understanding now together with answer from @Sibiraj PR

Comment: after some consideration, i will mark this as helpful. i have learn much this answer including the answer from @SibirajPR

Comment: ow, never know this feature before, thanks again, learn again. haha

Comment: As per your requirement, I update my answer. Actually i did the main part for your by using `print_r`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

```
$form_data = (array)$request->form_data;
foreach ($form_data as $key => $value) {
 echo "Key: $value->id; Value: $value->docno";
}
```

Comment: simple and to the point, in order to get the value, i have to access the object  properties as explained by @Frayne Konok